# Help with AlphaNumeric array

Tags: arduino-leonardo, array

I have a Leonardo board and I want to set up my pins to input in one shot using a for loop but the problem is with the analog pins I can't see how to set up a mixed alphanumeric array it gives me some errors.

Code:

```cpp
// including keyboard.h library for the keyboard functions
#include <Keyboard.h>


// setting Arrays for looping later
   int myIntPins[12] = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13};
   int myChar[12] = {97, 98, 99, 100, 101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108};
  int myChar2[6] = {109,110,111,112,113,114};
 myCharPins[6] = {"A0","A1","A2","A3","A4","A5"};
  int a;
  int x;
  int i;



void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:



 //Setting up Digital Pins 
for (int i=0; i <= 11; i=i+a){
  pinMode(myIntPins[i],INPUT);
  }

//pinMode(2, INPUT);
//pinMode(3, INPUT);
//pinMode(4, INPUT);
//pinMode(5, INPUT);
//pinMode(6, INPUT);
//pinMode(7, INPUT);
//pinMode(8, INPUT);
//pinMode(9, INPUT);
//pinMode(10, INPUT);
//pinMode(11, INPUT);
//pinMode(12, INPUT);
//pinMode(13, INPUT);

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// setting up Analog Pins to Digital
for (int x=0; x <= 5; x=x+a){
  pinMode(myCharPins[x],INPUT);
  }
//pinMode(A0,INPUT);
//pinMode(A1,INPUT);
//pinMode(A2,INPUT);
//pinMode(A3,INPUT);
//pinMode(A4,INPUT);
//pinMode(A5,INPUT);

// starting keyboard 
Keyboard.begin();

}


void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  //if pin 2 is pressed then send the a key/char  
 // if (digitalRead(2) == LOW) {Keyboard.write(97);}

// instead of doing an if one by one doing a loop all in one shot
// this loop for regular digital pins
a=1;
  for (int i=0; i <= 11; i=i+a){
    if (digitalRead(myIntPins[i]) == LOW){
      Keyboard.write(myChar[i]);
      }
      }
a=1;
  // this loop for the analog pins now working as digital pins
  for (int x=0; x <= 5; x=x+a){
    if (digitalRead(myCharPins[x]) == LOW){
      Keyboard.write(myChar2[x]);
      }
      }

  delay(10);

  }
```

Error:

```cpp
    Arduino: 1.8.7 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Leonardo"

Mandar_Keyboard_Key_1:10:2: error: 'myCharPins' does not name a type

  myCharPins[6] = {"A0","A1","A2","A3","A4","A5"};

  ^

C:\Users\manue\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\Mandar_Keyboard_Key_1\Mandar_Keyboard_Key_1.ino: In function 'void setup()':

Mandar_Keyboard_Key_1:45:11: error: 'myCharPins' was not declared in this scope

   pinMode(myCharPins[x],INPUT);

           ^

C:\Users\manue\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\Mandar_Keyboard_Key_1\Mandar_Keyboard_Key_1.ino: In function 'void loop()':

Mandar_Keyboard_Key_1:77:21: error: 'myCharPins' was not declared in this scope

     if (digitalRead(myCharPins[x]) == LOW){

                     ^

exit status 1
'myCharPins' does not name a type

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

If I change my code I to this, I get a different error.

Code:

```cpp
// including keyboard.h library for the keyboard functions
#include <Keyboard.h>


// setting Arrays for looping later
   int myIntPins[12] = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13};
   int myChar[12] = {97, 98, 99, 100, 101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108};
  int myChar2[6] = {109,110,111,112,113,114};
  char myCharPins[6] = {"A0","A1","A2","A3","A4","A5"};
  int a;
  int x;
  int i;



void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:



 //Setting up Digital Pins 
 a=1;
for (i=0; i <= 11; i+=a){pinMode(myIntPins[i],INPUT);}

//pinMode(2, INPUT);
//pinMode(3, INPUT);
//pinMode(4, INPUT);
//pinMode(5, INPUT);
//pinMode(6, INPUT);
//pinMode(7, INPUT);
//pinMode(8, INPUT);
//pinMode(9, INPUT);
//pinMode(10, INPUT);
//pinMode(11, INPUT);
//pinMode(12, INPUT);
//pinMode(13, INPUT);

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// setting up Analog Pins to Digital
for (x=0; x <= 5; x+=a){pinMode(myCharPins[x],INPUT);}
//pinMode(A0,INPUT);
//pinMode(A1,INPUT);
//pinMode(A2,INPUT);
//pinMode(A3,INPUT);
//pinMode(A4,INPUT);
//pinMode(A5,INPUT);

// starting keyboard 
Keyboard.begin();

}


void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  //if pin 2 is pressed then send the a key/char  
 // if (digitalRead(2) == LOW) {Keyboard.write(97);}

// instead of doing an if one by one doing a loop all in one shot
// this loop for regular digital pins
for (i=0; i <= 11; i+=a){if (digitalRead(myIntPins[i]) == LOW){Keyboard.write(myChar[i]);}}

  // this loop for the analog pins now working as digital pins
  for (x=0; x <= 5; x+=a){if (digitalRead(myCharPins[x]) == LOW){Keyboard.write(myChar2[x]);}}

  delay(10);

  }
```

Error:

```cpp
    Arduino: 1.8.7 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Leonardo"

Mandar_Keyboard_Key_1:10:54: error: too many initializers for 'char [6]'

   char myCharPins[6] = {"A0","A1","A2","A3","A4","A5"};

                                                      ^

exit status 1
too many initializers for 'char [6]'

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Comment: If you show what the difference is between the two sets of code, it would be helpful

Comment: why did you think it should be string "A0"? you have `pinMode(A0, INPUT)`, not `pinMode("A0", INPUT)`

Comment: @Juraj Idk I thought that int was for integer numbers and a mix of letters and and number would be a string that's all don't blame me I didn't go to school for programming it's just a hobby that I like and I'm learning you know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of those "A1" "A2" pins have other numbers that go with them.  The A1 or A2 is #defined in the core to be some number.  You can just use A1 or A2 and it will work.

For example, try this line and see what it prints:

```
Serial.println(A0);
```

And for your pins, just put A0, A1, etc. in your int array and leave the quotes off.  Those symbols are being replaced by numbers because they're defined constants.

```
int myIntPins[12] = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13, A0, A1, A2};
```

Comment: That worked just fine   Thanks a lot!!!